# Update the subDcoument attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document having schema like bellow

```
{  
   "Personal":[  
      {  
         "name":"Test_Name",
         "isActive":true
      }
   ]
}
```

am trying to update this as below using java driver.

```
collections.updateMany(new Document("Personal.name", "Test_Name"), new Document("$set", new Document("Personal.$.isActive", false)))
```

But unfortunately this trows an error

`"The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: Personal.$.isActive`"

But if i modify the above update filter something like

```
collections.updateMany(new Document("Personal.name", "Test_Name"), new Document("$set", new Document("Personal.0.isActive", false)))
```

it works.

Can any one help me in understanding whats wrong in using "$" in my 1st update statement?

Here is some more code spinets

**Creating the collection object:**

```
collections = mongoConnection.establishConnection()
```

**MongoConnection object:**

```
public MongoConnection() {

        StringBuilder connectionString = new StringBuilder();
        connectionString.append("mongodb://url_with_port_and_server")
        client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(connectionString.toString()));
        db = client.getDatabase("test");
        collections = db.getCollection("test");
    }

    public MongoCollection<Document> establishConnection() {
        return collections;
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        client.close();
    }
```

Comment: They should work exactly the same way. What is your java driver and mongo db version ?

Comment: Both are 3.4.0 version!

Comment: Can you add little bit more code ? Code where you create connection and define collection.I don't see any update method in the driver.

Comment: The code spinet i have pasted above is the exact same code which i am using for update!

Comment: Can you add code where you are creating mongo client ?

Comment: I have updated the post !

Comment: I have hard time finding `update` method in `MongoCollection` class. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/. are you sure you have the right method ?

Comment: I got your point now.. I have updated the posts!! I was using `updateMany`. My Apologies for missing that point

Comment: You don't have `upsert` value set to true. Do you ? The queries ran fine for me.

Comment: I haven't sent anything explicitly set that.   I have `collections.updateMany(filter, Document)` only.